# Launching QThreads in PyQt5 using moveToThread. One thread fails to launch properly

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread, pyqt5

I have 4 worker threads in my (semi)working example below. I can only make the first three worker threads work. How can I get the 4th thread to run?

`print(QThread.idealThreadCount())` returns '8' on my laptop.

I can reorder the code to make any combination of the 3 workers run.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import time

class A(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('A', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class B(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('B', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class C(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('C', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class D(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('D', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)

class window1(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super().__init__ () #parent widget
        print(QThread.idealThreadCount())

        self.thread1 = QThread()
        obj1 = A()
        obj1.moveToThread(self.thread1)
        self.thread1.started.connect(obj1.run)
        self.thread1.start()

        self.thread2 = QThread()
        obj2 = B()
        obj2.moveToThread(self.thread2)
        self.thread2.started.connect(obj2.run) 
        self.thread2.start()

        self.thread3 = QThread()
        obj3 = C()
        obj3.moveToThread(self.thread3)
        self.thread3.started.connect(obj3.run)
        self.thread3.start()

        self.thread4 = QThread()
        obj4 = D()
        obj4.moveToThread(self.thread4)
        self.thread4.started.connect(obj4.run)
        self.thread4.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
w = window1()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not storing a reference to `obj1`, `obj2` etc. As they have no parent (which is required to use `moveToThread`) they are being garbage collected at the end of the `__init__` method. The `time.sleep(1)` you add simply delays the end of the `__init__` method and the garbage collection.

If you store a reference to the objects (eg `self.obj1 = ...`) then all your threads should run correctly.

Comment: but if I have many threads, after storing them in a list such as self._threads, how can I remove them after they are finished?

Comment: @Shuman please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This isn't really the place to expand and the answer may depend on your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out if I add a `time.sleep(1)` delay at the vert end of the `__init__` method, all threads now work....

I would like to understand why however. A better answer will be appreciated.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
import sys
import time

class A(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('A', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class B(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('B', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class C(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('C', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)
class D(QObject):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            print('D', time.ctime())
            time.sleep(1)

class window1(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super().__init__ () #parent widget

        self.thread1 = QThread()
        obj1 = A()
        obj1.moveToThread(self.thread1)
        self.thread1.started.connect(obj1.run)
        self.thread1.start()

        self.thread2 = QThread()
        obj2 = B()
        obj2.moveToThread(self.thread2)
        self.thread2.started.connect(obj2.run) #this sets up a signal in the other direction??
        self.thread2.start()

        self.thread3 = QThread()
        obj3 = C()
        obj3.moveToThread(self.thread3)
        self.thread3.started.connect(obj3.run) #this sets up a signal in the other direction??
        self.thread3.start()

        self.thread4 = QThread()
        obj4 = D()
        obj4.moveToThread(self.thread4)
        self.thread4.started.connect(obj4.run)
        self.thread4.start()

        time.sleep(1)

app = QApplication(sys.argv) #every pyqt application must create an application object
w = window1()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```